# How to deploy an Angular 2 **website** with different meta tags for each page?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, web-deployment

How do you transition from:

```
# This URL is served BY THE SERVER.
http://example.com/movie/basic-instinct
```

To:

```
# This the SAME URL, but served BY ANGULAR in the client's browser,
# with `movie/basic-instinct` as the current path.
http://example.com/(index.html#)movie/basic-instinct
```

PLEASE keep reading before hitting your keyboard. :)

I'm NOT interested in solutions that redirect **all requests** to `index.html` to let Angular's router take over.

I DO want my server to respond to **ALL INITIAL REQUESTS** itself because I'm building a website (not an app) and I do need to serve a different page for each URL, with the proper Facebook Open Graph Tags, Twitter Card Tags, etc. But **ALL SUBSEQUENT "REQUESTS"** (which are no longer actual HTTP requests, but just the user navigating the app/site) should be handled by Angular's router.

How do I do that?

If I generate a static HTML file for all pages, then the initial request could serve the Angular app at http://example.com/movie/basic-instinct/(index.html), but... Angular's router would never be able to navigate out of the `movie/basic-instinct/` path...

UPD. For those of you familiar with Angular Universal, they call the part I'm interested in [transition from server view to client view](https://universal.angular.io/overview/). But they don't mention the router or URL redirection in their docs, they only explain how to transition from static HTML (generated by the server) to Angularized HTML (generated by the client).

Comment: Update a header section of the document.

Comment: @RomanC. What do you mean? What's a header section? What's a document?

Comment: On the next cycle of change detection when document is GC-ed you provide http header section to read from the requested object.

Comment: To handle the routing question, have you tried setting your <base href> to a fully qualified path instead of the usual <base href="/">  ? example:<base href="http://example.com/"> 

Unfortunately, I don't have the right environment to test that out for myself with angular2's router right now.